# Object Identification using xpath with SeleniumLibrary and robotframework

Tags: testing, selenium, xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm testing a web application using RobotFramework. I want to identify objects by xpath using the keyword `Click Link`but it didn't work. Every time, i get `FAIL   Timed out after 5000.0ms`.
Example:
[image]

Comment: Does it finds element?(without robot?)

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand your question.

Comment: U want to identify objects by xpath. Is that element finded?
Did U know how to locate element with xpath(in pure selenium, or selenium IDE)?

Comment: Yes, I worked before with both Junit/Selenium webdriver and i can locate element using xpath

Comment: Try doing this first: Set Selenium Timeout    30s. The default timeout is 5s for any command to complete. Is your DOM crazy huge and displayed on a slow machine?

Comment: In fact, the problem is related to Selenium2Library like i explained below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use xpath to identify your locator, you have to specify it in your statement:

```
Click Link  xpath=//i[2]a(...)
```

This is mentioned in the [library doc](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html): "By default, when a locator value is provided, it is matched against the key attributes of the particular element type. For example, id and name are key attributes to all elements, and locating elements is easy using just the id as a locator. [...]. It is also possible to specify the approach Selenium2Library should take to find an element by specifying a lookup strategy with a locator prefix"

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact, I have a problem with importing Selenium2Library. It's displaying in red and my test finish with failure.

Comment: This is not true. S2L detects the // and will interpret as XPath. This is however, an undocumented feature. See https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/src/Selenium2Library/locators/elementfinder.py#L93.

Comment: I totally agree with you, i know that S2L support identification object using xpath but the problem that i really face is that my test failed when i use S2L and it did work with SL. I did install S2L but i have this message "Suite setup failed:
No keyword with name 'Start Selenium Server' found". It's like S2L doesn't exist. And also there is any log error related to importing S2L